# Creating Batch file to run exe. and output to log file via GPO startup/shutdown

Tags: batch-file

I am having some trouble creating a batch file, I need it to remove a .msi file first and then run a .exe file this is what I have so far.

```
echo on 

title remove mimecast 3.5.6

if exist c:\windows\mimecastrem.tag goto alldone

msiexec.exe /x {86C4653D-E9B2-4421-8578-D2B953FFAEDA} /qn /L "C:\windows\mimecast.log"

start \\fcmsvr2\MimecastMSO\deploymimecast.exe /zap

echo. >c:\windows\mimecastrem.tag

:alldone

rem exit
```

If I run this in DOS logged on the pc it runs ok, I have tried to add this to a GPO startup and shutdown and the batch runs but only removes the .msi file and won't start the .exe, is there a way to add logging to this so I can see why it isn't running?

Thanks
David

Comment: Add a `pause` before and after the `start` line for debugging.  You might find permissions to be the issue, if the system account if being used, as it does not have access to network resources.

Comment: I tried pause and this confirmed that the script is working, but when adding this to logon gpo it won't run, start \\fcmsvr2\MimecastMSO\deploymimecast.exe /zap
how do I change it from the system account?

Comment: I don't know what GPO is so I can't advise.  Was there an error message on the console before the second pause?

Comment: sorry GPO is group policy object, which I have setup to push the batch file out in AD, I think this could be a permission issue possibly. No there was no error when running manually, just won't run on automatically on start-up.

Comment: You can't change the account under which it runs (easily). Why not put the requisite files in the GPO location so that anything that can access the script can access the requisite files?

Answer (score 0):

## Create a Wrapper Script to Capture the Output

When I try to run batch commands from a GPO, I usually have two batch files:

- One batch file does all the work.
- One to call the other and redirect all the output.

This way, if the important batch file has syntax problems (usually due to the contents of variables or other conditions on the machine), I still see something in the log.

**batch_worker.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

@ECHO Proceeding with important tasks...
REM do other stuff (delete, install, etc.)
```

**batch_wrapper.cmd**

```
CALL %~dp0batch_worker.cmd > C:\Windows\TEMP\batch_worker.log 2>&1
```

## Self-Wrapping

Another option that I occasionally employ is to have the script invoke itself, redirecting the output.

**batch_worker.cmd**

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

IF NOT "%_LOGGING%"=="1" (
    SET _LOGGING=1
    CALL "%0" %* > C:\Windows\TEMP\batch_worker.log 2>&1
    EXIT /B %ERRORLEVEL%
)

@ECHO Proceeding with important tasks...
REM do other stuff (delete, install, etc.)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried both but the log file just seems to output bacth file, it doesn't tell me if things are failing or successful.

Answer (score 0):

## Network Files from GPO

Any startup scripts that run on a Windows machine will have the network identity of the computer account (`COMPUTERNAME$`). This account doesn't usually have access to most network resources. The one exception is the GPO. All computer accounts have access to the GPO (which is stored as files).

If your script needs other files:

- Store them in a world-readable network location (or grant any domain member RX access).
- Store them with the GPO.
  When you create/add a startup script, the GPMC snap-in gives you access to the network location (under SYSVOL) where the script should reside. Use that UNC path to save any other files the script needs access to.

Comment: I have re-created the GPO and added my batch file along with the .exe file into the sysvol machine startup etc folder again the GPO runs on startup removing the .msi part but still doesn't run the .exe file, is there anything permission wise I am missing?

Comment: I have now put the batch file in is \\fcllp.lan\SysVol\fcllp.lan\Policies\{763BE5F3-610B-49BD-A7E9-045503C0DD33}\Machine\Scripts\Startup\MSORemoval.bat

Comment: You need to put the .EXE (and any other file, not stored on every machine the GPO will apply to, the script needs to run) in the same directory as the .BAT file. The problem seems to be that the machine account does not have access to `\\fcmsvr2\MimecastMSO`.